# Локальные переменные в Java

Tags: java, ооп, переменные, методы, типы-данных

Собственно говоря, суть моего вопроса можно свести к следующему: почему мы в обязательном порядке должны присваивать начальное значение локальным переменным, чтобы у нас появилась возможность их как бы то ни было использовать? Почему для локальных переменных отсутствуют значения по умолчанию? С чем это может быть связано?

И ещё один интересный момент, который напрямую связан с моделью памяти в языке программирования Java. На каком этапе локальная переменная добавляется в стэк? На этапе объявления? Или всё же на этапе присваивания начального значения? Ведь если мы изначально выделяем какие-нибудь 4 байта для хранения значения типа *int*, то конкретное значение у нас уже имеется (его будет составлять совокупность двоичных разрядов, которые мы уже зарезервировали под переменную). В общем, хотелось бы разобраться во всех этих вопросах. Всем крайне благодарен!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У компилятора просто нет возможности определить обращаешься ты к проинициализированой переменной в классе или нет, потому на всякий случай им даются стандартные значения. А вот для локальных переменных можно отследить, что она не была проинициализирована и кинуть ошибку.

Изначально, объявив переменную это всего лишь указатель на участок памяти, и содержит она то, что было в этом участке памяти до этого, то есть мусор. Чтобы мусора там не было, переменной нужно присвоить значение. То есть, стандартное значение у переменных класса это скорее костыль, для избежания получения "мусора" из переменной. А для локальных можно кинуть ошибку на стадии компиляции

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что "мусор" является каким-то случайным сочетанием двоичных значений?

Comment: @Lexoid условно случайное сочетание. Там находятся данные от старых переменных, объектов или даже других процессов. Память освобождается, вызовом какого-то метода free, теряя ссылку на переменную, но данные все еще остаются в памяти

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста примите его.